# why viewpager only show a empty view?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I try to use `ViewPager`and`PagerAdapter` to show some image,but i face a problem.This is my code.

```
Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position){
  View view = ....
  Textview textview = (TextView)view.findViewById();
  container.addView(textview);//show add view
  return view;
}
```

I should return this `view`, but i try to explore the source code of `ViewPager`. but i can not find the the function of that we should return `view` which be added to `ViewPager`(`container.addView()`).Sorry i am not good at English.Can you explain the reason that the `ViewPager` show empty `View` .I do not know why need `container.addView(view)`and `return view`.

Comment: what is the question about?

Comment: why we neeed use `container.addView(view)`and`return view`.why viewpager need do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace below line :**

```
container.addView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add view to the container not textview, so your modified code should be

```
Object instantiateItem (ViewGroup container, int position){
  View view = ....
  Textview textview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
  container.addView(view);//show add view
  return view;
}
```

Comment: I know should add view.but i do not the reason.I want to know why do this.

Comment: To Create the page for the given position you need to pass the view to the view group, 'instantiateItem' returns view to do recycling of views for pager adapter. for more information you must read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html